# Sum up values of associative array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have an associative array in php like

```
$aData['key1']['key2']['key4'] = value1;
$aData['key1']['key2']['key5'] = value2;
$aData['key1']['key2']['key6'] = value3;
```

I saved this array into a mongodb collection

```
{    
"_id": ObjectID(),
"client_id": NumberLong(123),
"time": ISODate("..."),
"data": {
    "key1": {
        "key2": {
            "key4": value1,
            "key5": value2,
            "key6": value3
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
{    
"_id": ObjectID(),
"client_id": NumberLong(123),
"time": ISODate("..."),
"data": {
    "key1": {
        "key2": {
            "key4": value1,
            "key5": value2,
            "key6": value3
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
},
{...}
```

How can I now sum up values of key4, key5, key6 for key1 and key2 for given client_id and time?

I tried:

```
db.getCollection('...').aggregate( [ 
    {$match: {client_id: 11}}, 
    {$project: {'_id': 1, 'client_id': 1,'data.key1': 1}}, 
    {$group: {_id: '$client_id', sum: {$sum: "$data.key1.key2.key4"}}} 
])
```

but sum is always 0.

Comment: use aggregation framework

Comment: I tried:  db.getCollection('...').aggregate(
    [
        {$match: {client_id: 11}},
        {$project: {'_id': 1, 'client_id': 1,'data.key1': 1}},
        {$group: {_id: '$client_id', sum: {$sum: "$data.key1.key2.key4"}}}
        
    ]
) but sum is always 0.

Comment: It should be part of the question really.

Comment: You don't need to project before group, and make sure `value1` is a number.

Comment: Damn, values were stored as strings. :( But how can I archive that sums are in an array structure as the saved data? Like data.key1.key2.key4: {$sum: "$data.key1.key2.key4"}

Comment: Yes............